# Non blocking function for UDP chat

Tags: c, udp, sleep, nonblocking

In my UDP chat, I receive and parse successfully the packages.
Right after parsing a package, I want to execute a function `func()` :

```
void func(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     printf("Hello World");
     sleep(5);
 }
}
```

As `sleep()`is a blocking timer, I can't receive packages while `func()`is executed. I am trying to build a UDP chat without threads. How can I make `func()`non blocking so I can receive packages and execute `func()`simultaneously ?

Comment: Remove the sleep()?

Comment: I want to print the message "Hello World" each 5 seconds.

Comment: Have you considered using [`select()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/_newselect.htm) for your UDP communication?

Comment: I have. I used `select()` a first time to receive packages.
I tried to use another select to execute my function, but it didn't work.
I set all the fd_set arguments to NULL. But the second select seemed to block the first select.

Comment: It would do.  You should use only one select() call and write your app as an event-driven state machine.  That is the cost of avoiding the kernel-managed state machine of multiple  threads.

Comment: You could use alarm [signal](https://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) to schedule the hello world print.

Comment: @Mathieu printf() is not signal-safe:(

Comment: @MartinJames As I am going to use two timeouts, how is it possible to use only one select() ?

Comment: You build the timeouts into your state machine and set the select() timeout to the nearest timeout-time.